# Jekyll > Serve > Dev Config File > Being read but ignored on start

Tags: node.js, jekyll

**SHORT VERSION:**

On starting jekyll serve today, the additional dev config file is read but ignored. This is a recent problem. Previously read and actioned the dev settings as expected.

I am using jekyll 2.5.3.

Can anyone shed any light on what is causing this?

**LONG VERSION:**

I develop locally with Jekyll, then upload production builds to my web host.

When developing I fire up jekyll's server loading an additional dev config file (`_cong_dev.yml`) after the main config file to activate dev settings. The full command I use is:

`jekyll serve --draft --host=0.0.0.0 --config _config.yml,_config_dev.yml`

I use a grunt shell task - because I am lazy.

This has worked fine for some time now.

Today, however, localhost took me to the main page but links were in production format - i.e. with the domain for the siteurl tag.

From other issues, I then realised that settings in the dev config file were not being processed.

In both the build and server steps in the serve process, the dev config file is being read:

```
C:\sites\MYSITE>grunt serve
Running "shell:jekyllServe" (shell) task
Configuration file: _config.yml
Configuration file: _config_dev.yml
            Source: C:/sites/MYSITE
       Destination: C:/sites/MYSITE/_site
      Generating...
                    done.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for 'C:/sites/MYSITE'
Configuration file: _config.yml
Configuration file: _config_dev.yml
    Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

As you can see, the dev file is being acknowledged, but its looks like its contents are being ignored.

I can:

1. open the dev config file;
2. change it;
3. save it;

and this triggers a rebuild with all the dev settings activated again.

But it is less than desirable.

FYI:

- I have typed out the full jekyll command rather than using the grunt shell - as expected, no difference.
- I have not updated jekyll or any of its dependencies....
- ...EXCEPT I did update node.js from 4.5~ish to the current 6.2 recently.
- I did recently add a key:value pair for livereloading to the _config_dev.yml file, which I thought may have initially stuffed up the parsing of the yml. But I played around with that by turning the value into a string etc, and the problem persists.

I admit that I haven't tested rolling back the node.js. Partly because I can't really see how that would be a problem here, and partly because I need the current version for a node.js tutorial course I am doing.

However, I may try that if no other answers offer insight.

**EDIT:** I am using Jekyll 2.5.3.

**EDIT:** I also note that this issue seems *similar* to this: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4850 (So I will keep an eye on that).

Can anyone shed light on this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `jekyll -v` ? A repository url maybe ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel Following your comment, I have edited the question to advise that I am using Jekyll 2.5.3. No repository url, sorry. I am a bit of a novice!

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarrassing...

I am posting my answer in the event anyone else has this problem - unfortunately, it is not the first time I have had to own up to my own idiotic mistake.

To clarify, the issue was actually that the site was not loading in expected dev mode on `jekyll serve` but, as I found out, was loading in dev mode on subsequent regens.

The problem was caused because I had somehow at one point generated the site with output files mapped with a destination next to their respective .md files, and instead of the `/_sites` folder. The files were created in production format and not a dev format (so likely created from a build not a serve task).

So, for example, in my `/about` folder there was both an index.md (proper) and a production version index.html (improper).

I really don't know how I managed this, but I expect I improperly set up a grunt task at one point.

In the event, having those files there meant:

1. on `jekyll serve`, Jekyll simply created the site copying over the already created index.html file - so creating the site in production format; but
2. on subsequent regeneration, Jekyll rebuilt the site reading the .md files and creating it in the expected dev format.

I do not know why the first build process produces different results from subsequent build processes, but that is by the by.

In the event, deleting the additional generated files fixed the issue.